# How to use a DTM (Geotiff) as web based basemap?

Tags: dem, web-mapping, basemap, cesium, url

I created a DTM as geotiff and I want to use it at basemap in web based virtual globe Cesium. How can I carry out this task? Cesium has a terrain provider and it requeries an URL for basemap. How can I turn my geotiff image (DTM) to an URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Cesium Terrain Builder https://github.com/geo-data/cesium-terrain-builder
 It makes tiles based on the GeoTIFF and you need to use Cesium Terrain Server to serve those to CesiumJS. Docker Images of both are available